# FFmpeg - sharpening the high pass filter

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, highpass-filter

I'm writing the command that is resampling the audio file and adding the high-pass filter to it.

In the software that I'm using, the high pass filter is **very** sharp - the problem is that I don't know how to *sharpify* the filter in FFmpeg.

[I've experimented with some options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#highpass) but none succeded. How can I achieve that?

```bash
ffmpeg -i "Audio.wav" -ar 44100 -af highpass=f=5000 "Audio_HP.wav" -y
```

| What FFmpeg does | What I want |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1):

`highpass` is limited to the first- or second-order (presumably, IIR) filter. You need to design your own digital filter to implement a filter with sharper cutoff. To do so, I'd use [`aiir` filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aiir). But you need coefficients...

While I (a DSP engineer by trade) uses/used Matlab/Python-Scipy to design filters, I found [this website](http://jaggedplanet.com/iir/iir-explorer) useful. If you enter your filter specifications, it shows C code for the filter. Show the code for "Nth order" implementation, and copy the coefficients to ffmpeg command as follows:

```
aiir=k=[gain]:z=[bcoef]:p=[acoef]:f=tf:r=d
```

substitute `[...]` as space-separated coefficients with the name in the IIR Filter Explorer. (See the examples in the documentation)

Designing your filter, SB-Ripple controls how much the signal is killed below 5kHz (try -20 or -40 to start) and keep your filter order reasonable (say max 10). Too high of an order may cause numerical unstability.

Disclaimer: I've never run `aiir` myself but this should be the correct way to configure it.